# How to start preloading HTML5 video from a certain time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Can anyone please tell me how to start preloading HTML5 video from a certain time??

For example I want my player to start preloading from (00:15). I know we can use preload attribute to start preloading from the current position but what if I want my player to preload the video from a certain time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by loading only the metadata, then, once it is done set the `currentTime` to 00:15 and then set the `preload` attribute to auto.

Just to be sure the data starts to load, you can trigger `video.play(); video.pause()`.

```js
var vid = document.querySelector('video');

vid.onloadstart = function() {
  log('loadstart at ' + this.currentTime);
};

vid.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  log('loadedmetadata at ' + this.currentTime);
  vid.currentTime = 15;
  vid.setAttribute('preload', "auto");
  vid.play();
  vid.pause();
};

vid.onloadeddata = function() {
  log('loadeddata at ' + this.currentTime);
};

function log(data) {
  document.querySelector('#log').innerHTML += '<p>' + data + '</p>';
}
```

```css
#log {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 1em;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}
```

```html
<video controls="true" preload="metadata" height="170">
  <source type="video/ogg" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.ogv">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4">
</video>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll defiantly try it out. The thing is I want to start my video from 00:00 but i want my player to preload data from time 00:00 and 00:15 i want the player to preload data parallel to each other.

Comment: @ChaitanyaChoudhary that sounds a very strange request, could you elaborate on the why you need it? Or is it about two different players playing a same video? If so, it seems that each players does load its own data separately, even if the sources are the same.

Comment: So basically i've added a Chapters feature in my player and i want to preload each chapter. So that when user skips to say some chapter X i don't want him to wait till the video is loaded. I tried using multiple videos but the thing is i can not add more than 6 HTML5 videos on a single page.

Comment: well, the only solution that comes in my mind right know would be to start start loading an hidden video by mouse out of the chapter link, then replace the playing video with this new one. Hacky, and I'm not sure it will load enough data to avoid the user waits…

Comment: Futhermore, IMHO even if a solution existed, the loading of farther chapters will impact on the loading of actually playing chapter, which I don't think is good for user either.

Comment: No no i just want to load first 3 seconds or so. Well i tried using multiple videos but browser limits the maximum number of videos you can have on a page.

Comment: Please start a new question with all those requirements, I may have a solution but it slightly different from what was asked in OP.

Comment: Well it won't be the same question, I gave you a solution on "How to start preloading HTML5 video from a certain time" which may interest some future reader, You're new question should rather sound like "How to start preloading multiple parts/chapters of a same video" which won't interest the ones who only want to know "How to start preloading HTML5 video from a certain time"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259555/how-to-start-preloading-multiple-parts-chapters-of-a-same-video