# How to start preloading multiple parts/chapters of a same video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to preload various chapters of the same video. So that when someone jumps to a new chapter there's no buffering.

For example if first chapter starts from 00:00 and the next one starts from 00:15 I want my player to preload 2-3 seconds of each chapter beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this approach, but I'm not sure it's the best one :

- Use the [`canplay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/canplay) event. It will fire when enough data is loaded (a few frames).
- Each time it fires, go to your next chapter and wait until it fires again.
- Do so until you loaded all chapters, then remove the event and set its video's `currentTime` to 0.

**Javascript:**

```
var chapters = [50, 100, 200, 300];
var j = 0;
var vid = document.querySelector('video');

vid.addEventListener('canplay', canplay);

function canplay() {
  if (j < chapters.length)
    this.currentTime = chapters[j++];
  else {
    this.removeEventListener('canplay', canplay);
    this.currentTime = 0;
  }
}
```

*Please note that when you change the `currentTime`, there will still be a little time for browser to buffer images, even preloaded.*

```js
var chapters = [50, 100, 200, 300];
var j = 0;
var vid = document.querySelector('video');

vid.addEventListener('canplay', canplay);

function canplay() {
  if (j < chapters.length)
    this.currentTime = chapters[j++];
  else {
    this.removeEventListener('canplay', canplay);
    this.currentTime = 0;
    // remove the condom
    var c = document.querySelector('#condom');
    c.parentNode.removeChild(c);
    showLinks();
  }
}

function showLinks() {
  var links = document.querySelector('#links');
  links.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < chapters.length; i++) {
    var c = document.createElement('a');
    c.href = "#";
    // add an attribute to store the chapter time
    c.chapter = chapters[i];
    c.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // set the video to our time
      vid.currentTime = this.chapter;
    });
    c.innerHTML = 'chapter' + i;
    links.appendChild(c);
  }
}
```

```css
html,body{ margin:0 }
a { margin:.5em; }
#condom{ position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:170px; width:303px; z-index:9999; background:rgba(255,255,255, 0.7); text-align:center; }
#condom>span{ position:relative;  top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); }
```

```html
<video controls="true" preload="auto" height="170">
  <source type="video/ogg" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.ogv">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4">
</video>
<div id="links"></div>
<div id="condom"><span>Your video is loading</span></div>
```

**Pros** : It does what you ask.

**Cons** : you will have to wait a bunch of time before it's first loaded.

**Possible workaround**, use two videos, one playable right now, and the other one, with chapters, going to replace the first one :

```js
var chapters = [50, 100, 200, 300];
var j = 0;
var vid = document.querySelector('#withChapters');
var first = document.querySelector("#first");
vid.addEventListener('canplay', canplay);

function canplay() {
  if (j < chapters.length)
    this.currentTime = chapters[j++];
  else {
    this.removeEventListener('canplay', canplay);
    // We're not playing the first video ?
    if (first.paused) {
      // set us to its current position
      this.currentTime = first.currentTime;
      // remove the old one and let's replace it
      first.parentNode.removeChild(first);
      this.style.display = "block";
    }//else we'll do it later
    //anyway, show the links now
    showLinks();
  }
}

function showLinks() {
  var links = document.querySelector('#links');
  links.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < chapters.length; i++) {
    var c = document.createElement('a');
    c.className = "chapter_links";
    c.href = "#";
    // add an attribute to store the chapter time
    c.chapter = chapters[i];
    c.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // set the video to our time
      vid.currentTime = this.chapter;
      // he's still there?
      if (first) {
        // And he's playing ? so are we
        if (!first.paused) vid.play();
        // anyway, now is "later"
        first.parentNode.removeChild(first);
        vid.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
    c.innerHTML = 'chapter' + i;
    links.appendChild(c);
  }
}
```

```css
a { margin: .5em; }
```

```html
<video id="first" controls preload="auto" height="170">
  <source type="video/ogg" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.ogv">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4">
</video>
<video id="withChapters" style="display:none" controls preload="auto" height="170">
  <source type="video/ogg" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.ogv">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4">
</video>
<div id="links">Please wait while chapters are loading ...</div>
```

**pros**: solved the problem of first snippet.

**cons**: since you'll be loading two videos at the same time, the loading of chapters will take even more time, and the playing of the first video may suffer from this.